# How to handle authentication for Microsoft graph daemon/service

Tags: node.js, azure, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I want to build a daemon to read and write emails using my organisation's office 365 account. My team has a private Azure Instance (not linked with any O365) and i have no admin access to o365 other than my accounts credential. How can i build a daemon service that authenticate with ms-graph and read/write emails without any user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an application definition in the directory that has the Office 365 accounts.

You can either create it directly, or you can create it as a multi-tenant application in another directory. 
In the latter case, you need to grant it access to the Office 365 tenant's Azure AD.

If you haven't worked with Azure AD and the Microsoft Graph API before, I recommend you check out the samples. There are [some for node.js](https://github.com/search?q=nodejs%20sample%20user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories), but the principles are the same for [all other environments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks).